# XPath to select top-level elements not on the path to a given element

Tags: xml, xpath

Say I have an XML (sub-)tree like

```
  n
  |-a
  | |- b
  |-c
  | |- x
  | |- d
  |-e
```

Given I have a selector **X** that will select the node *x*, how can I select the top-most elements (i.e. excluding their children) that is not directly on the chain from *n* to *x*? So, for the example, the result should be [*a*, *d*, *e*].

Additionally, *n* is not necessarily the root of a document and the descendants of *x* should also be excluded.

Edit:

It's trivial to remove the nodes directly on the chain:

```
.//*[not(descendant::X or ancestor-or-self::X)]
```

So the question becomes: given an XPath that returns some disconnected trees, how to get the root node of each.

Edit 2:

Since people are interested in why: I am testing a site with a third-party widget that should generate a tree like `<n><c><x>...</x></c></n>` given container node *n* and content *x*. Here *c* may be one or more level of elements.

Now, in some cases the widget generates more tags than desired (e.g. siblings to *c* or *x*) and my test should select those elements out and report.

Comment: Please [explain why](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) you need to find the root element of a set of result nodes. Why not directly select the nodes you are interested in? Showing an _actual_ XML document might help. Also, I am not sure why `b` is not in the result set? It's not connected to `x` in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
.//*[not(descendant::X or ancestor-or-self::X)][parent::*[descendant::X]]
```